# How to export user lists and passwords in synology NAS

Tags: synology

I would like to know there is methods to export user lists and passwords in synology NAS device

Answer (score 4):

### Local

See user Greenstream's answer in the [Synology Forum](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/90855?reply=308674):

> 1. Download config backup file from the Synology
> 2. Change file extension from .cfg to .gzip
> 3. Unzip the file using 7-Zip or another utility that can extract from gzip archives
> 4. Download and install DB Browser for SQL LIte from http://sqlitebrowser.org/
> 5. Open the extracted ‘_Syno_ConfBkp.db’ file in DB Browser for SQL Lite
> 6. From the top menu bar select File, then Export, then Export as csv
> 7. In the export dialog select the table confbkp_user_tb
> 8. In the options
>      a. select column names in first line, Field separator character ,
>      b. Quote character "
>      c. New line characters ‘Windows: CR+LF(\r\n)’
> 9. Save the file to your desktop and open in Excel

### LDAP

Based on [ldap2csv.py](https://gist.github.com/JosefJezek/5644296) and [How to retrieve all the attributes of LDAP database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411847/how-to-retrieve-all-the-attributes-of-ldap-database) to determine the available attributes, using [python-ldap](https://www.python-ldap.org):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ldap

host = 'ldap://[ip]:389'          # [ip]: The ip/name of the NAS, using the default port
dn = 'uid=[uid],cn=[cn],dc=[dc]'  # LDAP Server Settings: Authentication Information / Bind DN
pw = '[password]'                 # LDAP Server Settings: Password
base_dn = 'dc=[dc]'               # LDAP Server Settings: Authentication Information / Base DN

filter = '(uid=*)'  # Get all users
attrs = ['cn', 'uid', 'uidNumber', 'gidNumber', 'homeDirectory', 'userPassword', 'loginShell', 'gecos', 'description']

con = ldap.initialize(host)
con.simple_bind_s(dn, pw)
res = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filter, attrs)
con.unbind()

print(res)
```

The used ports can be found [here](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/Network/What_network_ports_are_used_by_Synology_services).

Comment: Just to note - for newer DSM version, the downloaded file has a `.dss` extension, just rename to `.tar.xz` and extract as above.